# Edit biblatex APA Style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to edit the bibliography style of the `biblatex` style `apa`. With the help of Google, I'm almost done, but there are some few adjustments that have to be done. My style looks like that:

> Arlot, S./Celisse, A. (2010): A survey of cross-validation procedures for model selection, in: *Statistics Surveys*, *4*(1), 40-79.

But has to look like:

> **Arlot, S./Celisse, A. (2010):** A survey of cross-validation procedures for model selection, in: *Statistics Surveys*, 4(1), 40-79.

1. Authors have to be bold
2. I need the volume number not in italic
3. If possible an "in" between title and journal would be nice.

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, maxcitenames=4,natbib=true,doi=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\citet}                     %Year in brackets
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %Colon after year
% Slash instead of comma (und &)
\DeclareDelimFormat*{multinamedelim}{\,/\,} 
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}{} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{multinamedelim}
```

The `.bib` file contains:

```
@article{Arlot.2010,
 author = {Arlot, Sylvain and Celisse, Alain},
 year = {2010},
 title = {A survey of cross-validation procedures for model selection},
 pages = {40--79},
 volume = {4},
 issn = {1935-7516},
 journal = {Statistics Surveys},
 doi = {10.1214/09-SS054}}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the output you currently get I'm inferring that you are using an older version of `biblatex-apa` that produces citations and bibliography entries according to 6th ed. APA style. Currently, `biblatex-apa` produces 7th-ed. APA style and 6th-ed. APA style can be obtained from `biblatex-apa6`'s `style=apa6`. That's why the MWE uses `style=apa6`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa6, maxcitenames=4,natbib=true, doi=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat*{multinamedelim}{/} 
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}{} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{multinamedelim}

% 1: Bold names
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \printtext[bold]{%
  \ifnameundef{author}
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{nameaddon}%
     \ifnameundef{with}
       {}
       {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
        \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
        \setunit*{\addspace}}}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}}}

\renewbibmacro*{editorinauthpos}{%
  \printtext[bold]{%
    \global\booltrue{bbx:editorinauthpos}%
    \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{editor}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{apaeditorstrg}{editor}}%
       % need to clear editor so we don't get an "In" clause later
       % But we also need to set a flag to say we did this so we
       % don't lose sight of the fact we once had an editor for
       % various year placement tests
       \clearname{editor}%
       \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}%
       \setunit{\adddot\addspace}}}}

% 2: plain volume numbers
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}

% 3: in for @articles
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}}
  {\usebibmacro{in}%
   \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:in}%
    {}%
    {\global\booltrue{bbx:in}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \bibstring{in}%
     \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Arlot.2010,
  author  = {Arlot, Sylvain and Celisse, Alain},
  year    = {2010},
  title   = {A survey of cross-validation procedures for model selection},
  pages   = {40--79},
  volume  = {4},
  issn    = {1935-7516},
  journal = {Statistics Surveys},
  doi     = {10.1214/09-SS054},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{Arlot.2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: **Arlot, S./Celisse, A. (2010):** A survey of cross-validation procedures for model selection, in: *Statistics Surveys*, 4, 40–79.]

---

It should be noted that it can be quite tricky to modify `biblatex-apa` or `biblatex-apa6`   since the styles were specifically written to comply to the at times complex APA guidelines and are in general not intended to be customised beyond APA requirements.